# Content provider for bytearray in android

Tags: android

I have bytearray created from a selected pdf. I am creating contentprovider to attach this bytearray as gmail attachment and then sending a mail.  Mail received successfully with same file size and when I try to open the file with Adobe reader, it opens the file and showing the no. of pages (Eg: 1/3) but not displaying the content of any page (displaying empty/ white pages). I am not even getting any error. I am using the following code...

```
    File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + fileName);
    cacheFile.createNewFile();
    String str = new String(content);
    //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
    OutputStream osw = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
    //ByteArrayOutputStream osw = new ByteArrayOutputStream(content.length);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(osw);

    //Toast.makeText(this, content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //pw.println(content);
    pw.println(str);
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
```

Comment: content is the byte array of your pdf file?

Comment: yes.. bytearray created with inputstream.. using the following code.........  public byte[] returnPDFBytes(InputStream inStream)
    {
       byte [] tempbytes=null;
        try {
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
            tempbytes = new byte[dis.available()];
            int i = 0;
            while (dis.available() > 0) {
                tempbytes[i] = dis.readByte();
                i++;
            }
        return tempbytes;
    }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ur writing a String into your output file. I would recommand to use write() instead. Example:

```
byte[] content;

//...

File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + fileName);
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
f.write(content);
f.flush();
f.close();
```

EDIT:

According to your reply, is it really necessary to open the input file with this while-loop? Have you tried something like this to receive ur input pdf file byte array:

```
File inputPDF = new File("your.pdf");
byte[] inputPDFData = new byte[(int) inputPDF.length()];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputPDF));
dis.readFully(inputPDFData);
dis.close();
```

Comment: Its not working.. application itself is crashing if fileoutputstream is used...If the content (bytearray) is written directly the attachment is nly 1 kb... not the data...

Comment: Does it make any difference? As I am reading the pdf with inputstream. I dont want to use the physical path (File) and there is every possibility to have large pdf.. i am using while loop...

Answer (score 0):

```
    //if send email button clicked
        //check bytes and attach to mail
        if (bytes.length > 0) {
            try {
                createCachedFile(this, attachmentFileName, bytes);
                this.startActivity(getSendEmailIntent(this, "testuurmi@gmail.com", "Test", "See attached", attachmentFileName));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gmail is not available on this device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

public void createCachedFile(Context context, String fileName, byte[] content) throws IOException {
    File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir() + File.separator + fileName);
    cacheFile.createNewFile();
    BufferedOutputStream bostream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFile));
    bostream.write(content);
    bostream.flush();
    bostream.close();
}

public static Intent getSendEmailIntent(Context context, String email, String subject, String body, String fileName) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    //Explicitly only use Gmail to send
   // emailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail");
    //emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/email");
    //Add the recipients
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { email });
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    //Add the attachment to custom ContentProvider
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + AttachFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" + fileName));
    return emailIntent;
}
```